# Plausible Components for Zombie Immunization?

Tags: zombies

I know this is fictional based, but if there's any group with the collective knowledge to help with this question, it would be you guys.

## Request

Any suggestions for 4-5 items that could be collected for a fictional (yet convincing) immunization against an air-born, zombie virus.

## Infection Traits

- Zombie viral/microbial infection that is spread though direct contact as well as being air-born.
- Direct contact is any transfer of bodily fluids (blood, mucus, sweat, etc.), causing the infected to decline rapidly (12-24 hours) -- which the immunization is not designed for.
- The air-born strain remains dormant until the body's immune system is compromised (extreme illness, near death, etc.)

## Possible Components

- Anything related to immunization for rabies or any of the five, related viruses from Africa (since, in this fictional scenario, that's where it originates from): [obodhiang and kotonkan (African ephemeroviruses)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22305623), [Mokola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mokola_virus), [Lagos bat virus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3291461/), and the [Duvenhage virus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3291369/).
- Anything related to possible immunization for afflictions with similar symptoms, like [encephalitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encephalitis), [cerebral malaria](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3056312/), [tetanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetanus), etc.
- Components are not limited to medicinal ingredients, but can also
  consist of anything else, such as equipment needed to prepare the immunization.  For instance, Human diploid cell vaccines (HDCVs) are used to immunize against rabies, so any equipment that might be needed for that   process would work.
- If possible, components should be available within a relatively close distance to the CDC.  Roughly within this area: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Centers+for+Disease+Control+and+Prevention/@33.7987841,-84.3286166,1020m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1scdc!3m4!1s0x88f5047a3b061fb3:0x123010dbc2c635b2!8m2!3d33.7993178!4d-84.328008?shorturl=1

I know this is a crazy request.
The medical area is definitely not my expertise, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-Posting on different sites of the network and with different accounts is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

What are some elements of the classic zombie's metabolism that we could interfere with?

Dead

Think we'll have to assume this one isn't true. Cell death is exploding cell membranes leaving a big thing of goo roughly shaped like someone you once knew. For zombism to be curable, there still needs to be a person beneath the disease.

No Pulse

Could be your zombie microbe excretes a surfactant(s) that helps keep nutrients flowing in and waste flowing out. An ingredient that disrupt these would be helpful.

Hungry

Could be your zombie microbe also excretes insulin to convert sucrose into glucose for the quick growth of the microbe, and might be one of the key things that maintains the microbes dominance. An insulin suppressor could starve the microbe (and the host) of the biological energy it needs.

Incoherent Rage

Could be the other body chemistry changes send the brain spinning. Some antipsychotics might be effective in giving the host a chance to get a grip.

Penicillin

There may be some magic ingredient, like penicillin that interferes with only the microbes ability to hold it's cell membrane together. Maybe combined with an insulin suppresor to slow growth so that the antibiotic can be effective.

Cardio Stimulator

Nothing is restarting the heart, so your heroes will need to do that.

Bringing It All Together

The zombie microbes circulatory system, a series of chemical surfactants, may act as a barrier to treatment - expelling other treatment agents as soon as their administered. A TBD counter surfactant interferes with the zombie circulatory system resisting treatment. Something that inhibits insulin is administered to slow down the reproduction rate of the microbe. A targetted antibiotic then goes to work killing off the infection. An antipsychotic maybe not only helps the zombie to function, but helps assure chemical signals to the heart are once again being received clearly. At just the right time, the heart is externally restarted with a shock.

Just realized you're looking for an immunization.

Comment: A heads up: This question has been marked a duplicate of its cross-post (which itself is on hold as "Too Broad"). ;-)